# image in a css using Symfony

Tags: html, css, image, symfony

```
http://localhost:8000/bundles/delivveweb/images/laranja_active_top_ful.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

After much searching I found my problem is it to compile this css not generating the route up correctly

```
$ php app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

use this command to generate it the routes, however for images that use this code:

```
{% image 'bundles/delivveweb/images/facebook_active.png' %}
     <img src="{{ asset_url }}">
{% endimage %}
```

It is generated in html this url

```
<img src="/images/2f9279f_facebook_active_1.png">
```

And no css with this code:

```
li.nav-active{
    background-image: url('../images/laranja_active_top_ful.png');
}
```

It is generated in html this url

```
li.nav-active{
    background-image: url('../../bundles/delivveweb/images/laranja_active_top_ful.png');
}
```

can someone tell me how to generate the right route css something:

```
li.nav-active{
    background-image: url('../images/laranja_active_top_ful.png');
}
```

config.yml:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ DelivveWebBundle ]
```

base.html.twig:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' output='css/*.css'
    'bundles/delivveweb/css/*'
%}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

layout.html.twig:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
...
<li class="nav-active"><a href="#" >PERFIL</a></li>
...
```

Comment: in your url, you have /assets/ inbetween img and your png, take that out

Comment: Looks like you have "img/assets/yourimage.png", but in your file structure, it's just "img/yourimage.png"

Comment: actually I forgot to by the folder structure but has the assets folder inside img and then the image.

the error is not the way because at the time I send inspect this full path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install your assets, Symfony changes the route to /web/bundles/name-of-the-bundle/img.

So, you need to change this line:

```
background-image: url('../img/assets/laranja_active_top_ful.png');
```

To this:

```
background-image: url('../img/laranja_active_top_ful.png');
```

Comment: actually I forgot to by the folder structure but has the assets folder inside img and then the image
the error is not the way because at the time I send inspect this full path

Comment: @MarciusLeandro Did you try then to construct the path static? Maybe since you are putting in relative is adding the /app_dev.php/ or the /app.php/.

Comment: this within a bundle and not on my standard

Comment: @MarciusLeandro I'm sorry, I don't understand you.

Comment: the full path would be something like: /src/Delivve/WebBundle/Resource/img/assets/laranja_active_top_ful.png

And when I send impencionar using the google chrome tool
appears on the path http: // localhost: 8000 / src / Delivve / WebBundle / Resource / img / assets / laranja_active_top_ful.png

Comment: The src folder is only for the application. You need to install your assets in order touse them on the /web folder.

Comment: Then not to call the images in the folder / src?

How do you draw the images in my css then?

Comment: Once you install your assets try to make the full path since the /web directory. Example: http://example.com/bundles/bundlename/img/imgname.jpg

Comment: The link is giving an error: Example Domain

This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.

Comment: Thats because it's an example. You have to replace the domain and the bundle name in order to get the image correct url.

Comment: something like that: background-image: url('/bundles/DelivveWebBundle/img/assets/laranja_active_top_ful.png'); ?

Comment: Yes. But a relative path can easily fail so I recommend you to try also the full path to assure that you can access to the image.

Comment: It has not yet works something like this:
li.nav-active {
     background-image: url ('@ DelivveWebBundle / img / assets / laranja_active_top_ful.png');
}

Comment: Then make a virtualhost with the possible future url for example.

Comment: @DelvveWebBundle is not a valid route for CSS so you need to use the common url.

Comment: contiunua not working and when I send impencionar it returns an error:

li.nav-active{
    background-image: url('/src/Delivve/WebBundle/Resources/views/img/assets/laranja_active_top_ful.png');
}

error: http://localhost:8000/src/Delivve/WebBundle/Resources/views/img/assets/laranja_active_top_ful.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)